# Lots of Flow errors in React Native project

Tags: react-native, flowtype, expo

I created a React Native project from [Expo](https://expo.io/). Then I wanted to add [Flow](https://flow.org/) to it. I noticed in my `node_modules/react-native` folder there was a .flowconfig so I copied that to the root of my project. After running `flow` I got some warnings from files in `node_modules/exponent` so I added an ignore for that whole folder. Afterwards, I still get many errors when running `flow`. Here are a few:

```
node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:227
227:   /* $FlowFixMe */
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Error suppressing comment. Unused suppression

node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:1120
1120:     if (__DEV__) {
              ^^^^^^^ identifier `__DEV__`. Could not resolve name

node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/AnimatedImplementation.js:2162
2162:     if (__DEV__) {
              ^^^^^^^ identifier `__DEV__`. Could not resolve name
```

- Expo SDK version: 14.0.0
- Flow version: 0.37.0
- React Native version: 0.41.2

Answer (score 3):

You can suppress errors in **.flowconfig** file, in `[options]` section as follows:

```
[options]
suppress_type=$FlowFixMe

suppress_comment=\\(.\\|\n\\)*\\$FlowFixMe\\($\\|[^(]\\|(\\(>=0\\.\\(3[0-8]\\|[1-2][0-9]\\|[0-9]\\).[0-9]\\)? *\\(site=[a-z,_]*react_native[a-z,_]*\\)?)\\)
```

Then, in `[libs]` section, you should point so called *library definition* file, like:

```
[libs]
./libdefs.js
```

And in **libdefs.js** just declare:

```
declare var __DEV__:string;
```

These changes should resolve your errors. See:

https://flow.org/en/docs/config/options/#toc-suppress-comment-regex and

https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/creation/ for details.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it might have been an oversight on the flow types for that release version.

All of those errors look fairly harmless though so you could just ignore it. If you absolutely cannot ignore it, update to a later version of React Native that's locked to a different version of Flow? I've had good results personally (no errors) with React Native @ 0.42 and Flow @ 0.38.

Answer (score 0):

Found this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/43202) which recommended updating the flowconfig to use the [latest version from create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/react-native-scripts/template/.flowconfig). Seems to have worked for me.